# FactoryGirl – Retrieving attributes from another factory in a polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism, associations, factory-bot, belongs-to

I have a `Board` that belongs to an `Artist`. So far I was able to setup this **polymorphic** association in my boards factory as so:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :board do
    association :boardable, factory: :artist
    boardable_type "Artist"
  end
end
```

The pattern I have setup in my actual app requires the `name` of my board to be the name of the artist it belongs to.  I tried doing something like:

```
name boardable.name
```

But ended up getting this error:

```
ArgumentError: Trait not registered: boardable
```

What is usually the best way to retrieve attributes within a `belongs_to/polymorphic` association?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Polymorphic associations do not need an explicit `association` to be declared in FactoryGirl. The following has been verified and will work:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :board do
    boardable factory: :artist
    name { boardable.name }
  end
end
```

As far as your `Board`'s name is concerned, make sure to wrap the attribute value in brackets, or FactoryGirl might treat it as a trait :) The `boardable_type` attribute of your `Board` will be automatically set to the `boardable`'s class, so it doesn't even need declaring.

Comment: Thanks. There's no way to keep things within the boards factory?

Comment: With your updated answer, where did the name attribute go?

Comment: You might even be able to get away with putting `name boardable.name` as a normal trait in the factory block. I'm on a phone and thus can't test. Your main issue was including `association` in your relationship definition.

Comment: It seems it's not instantiating the name because I run into a presence validation error.

Comment: As far as your suggestion in your previous comment, doesn't seem to work (see question).

Comment: Sorry for taking so long...I've been driving. I got home and tried out your issue, and changed my answer to reflect the proper fix. Thanks for being patient :)

Comment: That last update seemed to do the trick! Thanks so much for your help on this one. It was greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a before :create. Something like this

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :board do
    ...
    before(:create) do |board, evaluator|
      # create artist factory here to associate board to
      # example below that isn't polymorphic but you get the idea
      FactoryGirl.create(:artist, name: "foo").boards << board
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This code would be incredibly slow when run in a full-fledged test suite.

Comment: There isn't a speedier alternative?

Comment: @Collin Graves, Plz explain why you think this would run any slower than an after(:build) in your answer

Comment: I am very dubious that this would run ```incredibly slow``` when run in a "full-fledged test suite". I have done this many times with no issues

Comment: @MilesStanfield I should've mentioned that its a `has_one` association where an artist has one board. How different would the setup be?

Comment: Sorry, I must have read your code wrong earlier. I was in a car coming home from vacation, so the screen was awfully small. :)